# Which parts of the certificate are signed?

Tags: security, certificate, x509

I'm using Strongswan vpn and i want to identify my clients by clients certificate (X 509), i want to issue each client a certificate with a unique serial number.

My question is simple, is the serial number part of the certificate is signed ?

In wikipedia it is written :

> Also included is an RSA public key (modulus and public exponent), followed by the signature, computed by taking a MD5 hash of the **first part** of the certificate and signing it (applying the encryption operation) using Thawte's RSA private key.

What is the first part that they talk about ? does he include the serial number ? if so does it safe to use it as an identifier ?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. http://security.stackexchange.com will be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A certificate binds an entity or identity to a public key. The binding occurs via a signature of an authority. So a entity (i.e., a *subject*) and its public key (for example, an RSA public key) gets signed.

> Which parts of the certificate are signed?

That would be the `toBeSigned` part (its really named that). See, for example, PKCS #10 or RFC 2986 [Certification Request Syntax Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2986).

`toBeSigned` includes:

- subject's distinguished name
- subject's public key
- other attributes, like key usage

> is the serial number part of the certificate is signed ?

Yes. Its set by the *Issuer* (the folks who sign the certificate), not the *Subject* (the person who has the public key).

> Also included is an RSA public key

That's the public key that gets bound to an entity or person (i.e., the subject's public key).

> followed by the signature

That's the signature that binds the entity or person to a public key (i.e., the issuer's signature).

> by taking a MD5 hash

That example is kind of old. SHA-256 is now being used.

> does [the first part] include the serial number ?

Yes. Its one of those "other attributes".

Answer (score 2):

The structure of a X509 Certificate is defined in [RFC5280](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt) chapter 4.1.1. What is signed is covered in chapter 4.1.2. In short there is subject, serial number, issuer, validity times, extensions and of course public key (and many other things).

So the short answer is YES, it is safe to do this as you have written.

But one thing should be mentioned. Serial number can have two different meanings (and usages). It can be serial number of the certificate (as mentioned in chapter 4.1.2.2 of in the RFC). Or it can be a part of the subject or issuer (chapters 4.1.2.4 and 4.1.2.6 of in the RFC). It was not clear which serial number did you have in mind.

Either way, it should still be doable and **safe** to do this **if you will make a validity checks on the client certificate** (revocation, chain to a trusted root, integrity ...) because if you can issue a certificate with serial number X so can I. But I can not issue a certificate from your CA because I do not have private key of your CA.